# Setting Python Executable Path in Atom Package (i.e. Autocomplete-Python) with Anaconda/Miniconda Python

Tags: python, autocomplete, anaconda, atom-editor, miniconda

I am having a tough time managing paths.

I have python installed natively with Miniconda3 (python came shipped with Miniconda3).

I want to setup atom packages, virtual environments.

[atom's autocomplete-python documentation](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python) (also in settings underneath package header) explains:

[Python Executable Paths to be formatted like this](https://i.github-camo.com/e848302819e030a60051b988ea556112bd5510ae/68747470733a2f2f636c6f75642e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6173736574732f3139333836342f31313633313336392f61616662333462342d396433632d313165352d396130362d6538373132613231343734652e706e67)

I have located two python executables to the following paths:

/Miniconda3/python

/Miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0/python

I also tried /$Miniconda3...

and prepending c:/...Miniconda3

(I don't think I understood $PROJECT or $PROJECT_NAME, but gave it a shot)

I have tried all these variations.
Rebooted as instructed.
Still no results.

I generate these two errors:

> Please set path to python executable manually in package
>   settings and restart your editor. Be sure to migrate on new settings
>   if everything worked on previous version.
>   Detailed error message: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Current config: C:\users\User\Miniconda3\python
>
> Please set path to python executable manually in package
>   settings and restart your editor. Be sure to migrate on new settings
>   if everything worked on previous version.
>   Detailed error message: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Current config: /users/user/Miniconda3/python

In the past, I got around this by installing python globally on my system, then downloading and installing miniconda/anaconda, however, this seems hacky and I would like to understand how to do it the right way especially considering atom looks to support virtual environments and accomodates custom paths, and because I have struggled with paths in the past and want to figure them out.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a python environment and run:

```py
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

This is the location of python executable that should be set as the path variable in atom. I had the same issue and this resolved it for me.